# Como puedo bloquear la carga de un evento, si ya existe un evento para ese dia en fullcalendar?

Tags: condiciones, fullcalendar, calendar

Estoy tratando de bloquear la carga de un evento al hacer click en un día donde ya existe un evento previo. Es decir que solo me permita cargar un evento por día.

Estoy tratando de ponerle un condicional dentro de `dateClick` pero me da error.

Hay distintas funciones para limitar el numero de eventos que se ven en pantalla, pero no es lo que quiero.

Les dejo parte del código.

Muchas gracias.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var draggableEl = document.getElementById('listaeventospredefinidos');
    var draggable = new FullCalendar.Draggable(draggableEl, {

      itemSelector:'.fc-event',
      eventData: function(eventEl){
        return{
          title:eventEl.innerText.trim()
        }
      }
    });
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {


      droppable:true, 
      dayMaxEvents: 1,
      editable: true,
      events: '/sistema/datosreservas.php?accion=listar',
      
      
      
      dateClick: function(info) {
        var ahora=new Date();
        var fecha_evento = new Date(moment(info.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
        if(fecha_evento>ahora){


        limpiarFormulario();
        $('#BotonAgregar').show();
        $('#BotonModificar').hide();
        $('#BotonBorrar').hide();
      
        if (info.allDay) {
          $('#inicio').val(info.dateStr);
          $('#fin').val(info.dateStr);
        }

        $("#FormularioReservas").modal('show');
        }
      },
      
      eventClick: function(info){
        
        $('#BotonAgregar').hide();
        $('#BotonModificar').show();
        $('#BotonBorrar').show();
        $('#id').val(info.event.id);
        $('#pasajero').val(info.event.title);
        $('#habitacion').val(info.event.habitacion);
        $('#descripcion').val(info.event.extendedProps.descripcion);
        $('#inicio').val(moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
        $('#fin').val(moment(info.event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
        $('#colorfondo').val(info.event.backgroundColor);
        $("#FormularioReservas").modal('show');
      },
    
      
      slotEventOverlap:false,
      description: true,
      height: 600,
      locale: 'es',
      headerToolbar: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        
      },



    });
    calendar.render();
  });
```

Comment: ¿Y no puedes hacer que "/sistema/datosreservas.php?accion=listar" ya venga filtrado con solo un evento por día?